# Integrating Chutzpah test runner into Visual Studio Code?

Tags: jasmine, visual-studio-code, chutzpah

I am developing an angular application using Visual Studio Code - the IDE itself is great but can anyone point me to how to integrate Chutzpah Test Runner with the IDE? And possibly with the Unit Test Explorer?

Any help appreciated!